# WKwebview content covers the top status bar

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I followed [this](http://technical-itch.net/making-a-simple-hybrid-ios8-app-with-swift/) tutorial to create a WKwebview which worked but with one problem. The top status bar is covered by the content of the webView.

Since the webView IS the containerView, how then can the webView go under the status bar in code. Thanks

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var mainView : UIView?
var webView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView() // call parent loadView
    self.webView = WKWebView() // instantiate WKWebView
    self.view = self.webView! // make it the main view
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() // run base class viewDidLoad
    let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.google.com") // make a URL
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!) // make a request w/ that URL
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req) // unwrap the webView and load the request.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image]}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it by embedding a container view inside the main "root" view, then placed a webView inside the container and thus was able to control the container display to be under the status bar by setting its constraints

> Container View.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom

I must say I am amazed as to so many online tutorials that can benefit from some polishing-up/upgrade, "reader beware" which is difficult when you are learning, sigh.

Comment: Could you please show the code you ended up using? Specifically I'm interested in how you added the container and the `WKWebView`. Did you use the storyboard to add the container? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dev-iL I left this project and rust has built up on my xCode/swift. I know I was helped greatly by lynda.com lessons. Sorry not much help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what ended up working for me (very similar to Herbert Bay's answer).

**Swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Get height of status bar (iPhone X introduced a new status bar)
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        // Initialize the frame
        webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight, width: view.bounds.maxX, height: view.bounds.maxY)
        // Set background color of status bar (optional)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255.0, green: 248/255.0, blue: 248/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Setting **y** in **CGRect.init()** to the height of the status bar eliminates any overlapping of your web view and the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the `WKWebView` as subview of the container view and use the size of the status bar to init the `WKWebView` with `initWithFrame`. Happy to learn if there is a better approach.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
CGFloat heightStatusBar = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, heightStatusBar,
                                                           self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                           self.view.frame.size.height-heightStatusBar)
                                  configuration:webViewConfiguration];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```